Questions on Unified Sink API V2 Committer Guarantees
I'm working on developing a new version of the open-source
Delta-Flink Sink using the Unified Flink Sink V2 APIs and the
open-source Delta-Kernel library (https://delta.io/blog/delta-kernel/).
I have a few questions about the API guarantees provided by Flink's
exactly-once guarantees. For the following questions, you can assume I'm
forcing a single global committer using the org.apache.flink.streaming.api.connector.sink2.SupportsPreCommitTopology::addPreCommitTopology
API and mapping the incoming Committable DataStream to .global().
My questions:

For a given checkpointId, will the org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink2.Committer::commit API always be
called with all committables for that checkpointId? Is there any chance
of only some of the committables for that checkpointId being delivered,
perhaps due to a network delay, RPC delay, or even a lost end-of-interval
RPC call?

If so, will the org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink2.Committer::commit
API only ever be called with committables all belonging to the same
checkpointId? Or could they belong to multiple checkpointIds?


Thanks!
